# Why this tabulate function is not reading a two dimensional array in C?

Tags: cs50

I could use some help with my CS50 Runoff problem Particularly with my tabulate function.

I wrote the following code:

```
void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            int c = preferences[i][j];
            if (!candidates[c].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[c].votes++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

but when i check it, check50 detects the following errors:

:( tabulate counts votes when multiple candidates are eliminated
tabulate function did not produce correct vote totals
:( tabulate handles multiple rounds of preferences
tabulate function did not produce correct vote totals

I really do not see the problem.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't know the specification but incrementing `i` in both `for` loops looks suspicious.

Comment: haha I cant believe it Jeff!! that was the problem.